# Want to call method that will execute everytime, when visitor visit my app rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Want to call method that will execute everytime, when visitor visit my app rails. Where should I define it, tried in application controller.

```
def get_ip
   if request.remote_ip == '127.0.0.1'
       # Hard coded remote address
       '123.45.67.89'
   else
        request.remote_ip
   end  
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were doing right, you should define this method in ApplicationController only and call that in `before_action`. like:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :get_ip

  def get_ip
    if request.remote_ip == '127.0.0.1'
      # Hard coded remote address
      '123.45.67.89'
    else
      request.remote_ip
   end
  end
end
```

`get_ip` method will call every time as soon as request hits to `ApplicationController` or any action of any controller inherited from `ApplicationController`.

Comment: @Sontya: But be cautious, if you are using any gem and that will insert any middleware and any request responded back from the middleware then `get_ip` won't call.